# Weka Time Series Forecasting Package not recognizing uploaded data

Tags: weka

I'm new with Weka and I installed the Time Series Forecasting package, but it is not reading some of the data I upload.

I have a single column(attribute) of randomly generated numbers that I want to forcast, the problem is that after converting it to CSV or ARFF the Forecasting package cannot recognize it like it does other sets of data.

Is there a simple solution to this?
Must I add a date/time column or convert it different etc?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need a date/time column.

There's an example shown here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EANP32bQIUw

The slides for this video are here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tuXEy73YswQ3A2VW9GUlFabUk/view